# Function with classes and vectors variables in c++

Tags: c++, function, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I have a class named Party that includes a private variable named players which is type vector, sting.

```
class Party
{
    vector <string> players;

    public: 
    Party (string party_name, string boss)  {}; 
    ~Party() {};        

    vector<string> getNames() { return players; };

    void setNames (const vector<string> &new_players) { players=new_players; }

}
```

I want to write a friend function which will show if the variable P (aslo class with  a "Name" variable being private) is party of the Party.

```
void part_of_party (Party &party, P name)
{   
    bool found=false;

    for (int i=0; ( found==false && i<party.name.size() ); ++i)
    {
        if ( (party.name[i]).compare(name.getName()) == 0)
        {
            found==true;
        };
    }

    if (found==true) { /// }
    else { //// }
}
```

The compiler doesn't show any errors but no message is printed on the screen (as it supposed to).

Do you have any idea?
Thank you.

Comment: [Enable your compiler warnings](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z_Pqmo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is this

```
found==true;
```

which should be

```
found=true;
```

Normally newbies get this wrong the other way around, they use `=` when they should use `==`, but you have used `==` (equality) when you should  have used `=` (assignment). Your compiler should have warned you about this. Pay attention to compiler warnings, it will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Also, not an error, but

```
if (party.name[i] == name.getName())
```

is a more obvious way of writing

```
if ( (party.name[i]).compare(name.getName()) == 0)
```